How to set a variable during build, check it during release (classic pipelines)
I want to set a variable during build, which I can then check during release. Below is what I have tried after doing my research.

Add a variable to the build:


In the build pipeline, add a "Powershell Script" Task with an inline script like this:
Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SkipRelease;isOutput=true]true"


In the release, add a "Powershell script" with an inline script like this:
$skipRelease = $env:SkipRelease
Write-Output "SkipRelease variable is: $skipRelease"



I have tried several variations of this, reading the SkipRelease variable:
$skipRelease = "$(Build.DefinitionName.SkipRelease)"

...
$skipRelease = $(SkipRelease)

...
$skipRelease =  $($env:SkipRelease)

None of them work, SkipRelease is either not defined or empty, depending on which method I use - determined by looking in the logs.
Can I check if the SkipRelease variable is actually by the build? How can I read it from the release?

Are you using classical build/release pipelines?

Variables created with task.setvariable are not available outside the scope of a build.

I am using classic build/release pipelines

Using classical pipelines complicate things a bit :-) If you don't mind me asking, what is the criteria for setting SkipRelease to true or false?

@RuiJarimba It is not really relevant to the question what the criteria is, but since you ask: A check for a keyword in the commit message.

I was asking because there are a lot of predefined variables containing information about the triggering build, such as the branch name, etc.

@RuiJarimba If one of those predefined variables contained the commit message, that would actually have solved my problem. Unfortunately it does not.

Yes in your particular case these variables won't help. Anyway, I found a workaround - see my answer below. A word of advice: stop using classical pipelines, as these are kind of deprecated. YAML pipelines are much more flexible and powerful, not to mention all the advantages of having the pipeline and correspondent templates under source control :-)

Instead of pipeline variables use build tags.
For example, add a build tag named DeployApplication to a build that should trigger a release:
echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]DeployApplication"

Tag will be added to the build:

Then in the release artifacts configure a Continuous deployment trigger based on the branches and the build tags as follows:

